# How to center the text in TreeTableView Column?

Tags: java, javafx, treetableview

I've a JFXTreeTableView and i want to center the text of the data for each column.

there is one of my creating columns code :

```
JFXTreeTableColumn<TableData, String> DrinkColumn = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Drink");
    DrinkColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
    DrinkColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, String> param) {
                                            return param.getValue().getValue().Drink;
                                        }
                                    }
    );
```

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: a StringProperty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the color of a single data cell in a TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872477/change-the-color-of-a-single-data-cell-in-a-tableview) So, after setValue, you setCellFactory

Comment: Can you just do this in an external CSS file? `.tree-table-cell { -fx-alignment: center ; }` I don't use JFoenix, so I can't test.

Comment: thanks all of you for your comment !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use JFoenix, but using a standard `TreeTableView`, the following external CSS will center the text in tree table cells:

```css
.tree-table-cell {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}
```

Here's a SSCCE (the code above goes in `style.css`):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeTableViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeTableView<Item> table = new TreeTableView<>();
        TreeTableColumn<Item, String> col = new TreeTableColumn<>("Item");
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
        col.setPrefWidth(250);
        table.getColumns().add(col);
        TreeTableColumn<Item, Number> valueCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("Value");
        valueCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().valueProperty());
        valueCol.setPrefWidth(150);
        table.getColumns().add(valueCol);

        table.setRoot(createRandomTree(50));

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TreeItem<Item> createRandomTree(int nItems) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        TreeItem<Item> root = new TreeItem<>(new Item("Item 1", rng.nextInt(1000)));
        root.setExpanded(true);
        List<TreeItem<Item>> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(root);
        for (int i = 2 ; i <= nItems ; i++) {
            TreeItem<Item> item = new TreeItem<>(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(1000)));
            item.setExpanded(true);
            items.get(rng.nextInt(items.size())).getChildren().add(item);
            items.add(item);
        }
        return root ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you want to center only specific columns, then use a cell factory on the column and set a CSS class or PseudoClass on the cell:

```
valueCol.setCellFactory(column -> {
    TreeTableCell<Item, Number> cell = new TreeTableCell<Item, Number>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Number value, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(value, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(value.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("centered"), true);

    return cell ;
});
```

and modify the CSS accordingly:

```css
.tree-table-cell:centered {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}
```

The latter version gives

[image]